# Call Swift class method from Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, swift

I am using Objective-C to consume a Swift Code that I am turning into a Framework/SDK eventually.
I can not invoke the class Methods specifically to Objective-C, and I am getting this error

`No visible @interface for 'class' declares the selector 'method'`

Swift File

```
public class Example {

    public class func testOne() -> NSString {
         return "testOne";
    }

    public func testTwo() -> NSString {
         return "testTwo";
    }

}
```

Objective-C File

```
#import <ProjectModuleName-Swift.h>

@interface ...
@end

@implmentation ...
- (void) testing {
  Example *example = [[Example alloc] init];
  NSString *testOne = [example testOne]; // does not work ; No visible @interface for 'Example' declares the selector 'testOne'
  NSString *testTwo = [example testTwo]; // does work
}
@end
```

Obviously, by declaring `class func` it should require a different way to invoke it through Objective-C, but I have not seen any docs on this topic.

An example or help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Class methods are called on the class, not instances of the class:

```
NSString *testOne = [Example testOne];
NSString *testTwo = [Example testTwo];
```